# Sending filebeat outputs via http

Tags: logstash, filebeat, elk

I have a filebeat instance reading a log file, and there is a remote http server that needs to receive the log outputs via rest api calls.

For now I'm sending filebeat outputs to logstash, and make logstash do some filtering and passing the log the remote server (this is done using logstash http output plugin).

Would it be possible to remove the logstash server in the middle, and make the filebeat to make api calls directly?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the list of output supported by latest filebeat (7.10)  doesn't include a http or "rest api".

The current list of output :

- Elasticsearch Service
- Elasticsearch
- Logstash
- Kafka
- Redis
- File
- Console

More details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-output.html)